# Миграция сайта с joomla(2.5) на Wordpress, контент ZOO

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Поставлена задача миграции сайта с joomla(2.5) на Wordpress
проблемой стал контент ZOO, какие есть способы переноса? Я знаю что для FG Joomla to Wordpress есть аддон ZOO стоимостью 25$ но хотелось бы узнать об альтернативных методах?

Answer (score 1):

... хм...  *(из цикла извращённое программирование)*:

1. ставим голый вордпресс,
2. формируем аналогичную структуру сайта (создавая по два-три пробных поста),
3. делаем бэкап баз данных двух  сайтов,  находим таблицы отвечающие за контент,  сохраняем(!),
4. и путём нехитрых   манипуляций с заголовками ... адаптируем джумловскую базу данных  с  wp-шной.
5. делаем подмену бд
6. трясём бубном (проверяем)

... должно работать) (если не получилось, повторяем 4-6 пункт.)

.... самостоятельно создаём аддон, код выкладываем на github )